# React native: how to find an item in array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this array:

```
var arr = [{"3": "2"}, {"2": "6"}, {"4": "7"}, {"5": "9"}];
```

I cant get the value by index, i am trying to do this:

```
console.log(arr[3]); //output needed: 2.
console.log(arr[5]); //output needed: 9.
...
```

any help please?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to add sub categories to an array with the main category:

```
const [subcatsSelectedForNow,setSubCatsSelectedForNow]=useState([]);


const selectCat = (catid,maincat)=>{
var arr=subcatsSelectedForNow || [];
  arr.push({
    [catid]:maincat
  });
  setSubCatsSelectedForNow(arr);
};
```

Comment: Any reason you have that array? Its hard to work with since you should see stuff inside {} as key values.

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{ 3: "2" }, { 2: "6" }, { 4: "7" }, { 5: "9" }];
```

You simply can't achieve your accepted behavior using `console.log(arr[3]);`

First you need to find whether the property(catid) exist in the array or not & if it is exist then you can get the object value as below,

```
const find = (num) => {
  let obj = arr.find((item) => item[num]);
  return obj && obj[num];
};

console.log(find(3)); //Output -> 2
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.